# Delete an item from Python array based on an item being deleted from another array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am writing a code that will give me a month-by-month progress report of where my debts should be and how long it will take to pay them off. When one debt is paid, I want to delete that value from the array, along with the corresponding interest rate and minimum payment from their respective arrays, that way I can take the values (money) that were being spent on those debts to pay off the remaining ones faster.  Is there a way to index each value in each array so that when, let's say "Debt 5" for 865 dollars gets paid off, every value in every array that corresponds to that debt gets deleted?  Currently, each detail for each debt holds the same location in their respective array (i.e. Debt 1 is [0] in name, and its amount is also [0] in debt, and its interest is also [0] in interest, etc).

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import round

# Max amount you can spend per month on debts
budget = 1000 

# name your debts, balances, interests, and minimum payments
name = np.array(["Debt 1:", "Debt 2:", "Debt 3:", "Debt 4:", "Debt 5:", "Debt 6:"])
debt = np.array([250,300,7215,5500,864,1066])
interest = np.array([.1715,.0376,.0376,.0445,.0445,0])
minPayment = np.array([15,60,60,60,60,70])

# Miscellaneous variables for data storage and counting
index = [0]
intAccrued = []
month = []
i = 0
j = 0

# Loop through to calculate debt progress
while any(debt >=0):    
    debt = debt - minPayment + debt*interest/12
    debt[debt <=0] = 0

## This deletes the zero values from the debt index, now I need a way to delete
## the corresponding minPayments and interest values from the other arrays
    debt = np.delete(debt, index)

    print (round(debt,2))
    if sum(debt) == 0:
        break
    month
    i += 1
print (i, "Months")
```

Comment: You could create a array with the indizes of the 0-Values before deleting them. then you have the indizes for the other arrays.

Comment: @Justin Cooley Is the usage of numpy necessary? This seems like an over-application and could lead to code smell. Entire use case can be done in default Python.

Comment: Half your code is not actually used: `budget`, `index`, `intAccrued`, `month`, `j`. Also, your printing does not happen in the loop as it probably should.

Answer (score 1):

I would go a step further than using `numpy` and use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). `pandas` has a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), which is basically a table. You can operate on whole rows or columns at a time, for example by filtering a dataframe on some condition (here `df[df.debt > 0]`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": name, "debt": debt, "interest": interest, "minimum_payment": minPayment}).set_index("name")
#          debt  interest  minimum_payment
# name                                    
# Debt 1:   250    0.1715               15
# Debt 2:   300    0.0376               60
# Debt 3:  7215    0.0376               60
# Debt 4:  5500    0.0445               60
# Debt 5:   864    0.0445               60
# Debt 6:  1066    0.0000               70
```

Then your loop would be:

```
from itertools import count

for i in count(1):
    df.debt = df.debt - df.minimum_payment + df.debt * df.interest / 12
    df = df[df.debt > 0]
    if len(df) == 0:
        break
    print(f"Month {i}:")
    print(df)
    print()
```

Which gives the following output:

```
# Month 1:
#                 debt  interest  minimum_payment
# name                                           
# Debt 1:   215.226480    0.1715               15
# Debt 2:   122.264256    0.0376               60
# Debt 3:  7102.469139    0.0376               60
# Debt 4:  5380.746359    0.0445               60
# Debt 5:   692.979363    0.0445               60
# Debt 6:   856.000000    0.0000               70
#
# Month 2:
#                 debt  interest  minimum_payment
# name                                           
# Debt 1:   203.302425    0.1715               15
# Debt 2:    62.647351    0.0376               60
# Debt 3:  7064.723542    0.0376               60
# Debt 4:  5340.699960    0.0445               60
# Debt 5:   635.549162    0.0445               60
# Debt 6:   786.000000    0.0000               70
#
# ...
#
# Month 149:
#              debt  interest  minimum_payment
# name                                        
# Debt 3:  8.948222    0.0376               60
```

Comment: I haven't used pandas before, but this worked so well I went and ordered a book on it lol. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to suggest to use the class here and make the array of reference of class.
Here I have an example Just tried.

```
#creating a class with the required structure.
class Expence:
    name = ""
    dept = 0.0
    intrest = 0.0
    minPayment = 0

    def __init__(self,name,dept,intrest,minPayment):#here you can create methods to store the value to the class variables.
        self.name = name
        self.dept = dept
        self.intrest = intrest
        self.minPayment = minPayment

    def getData(self):
        return self.name, self.dept, self.intrest, self.minPayment

newExpence1 = Expence("Debt 1:",250,0.1715,15)
newExpence2 = Expence("Debt 2:",300,0.0376,60)
newExpence3 = Expence("Debt 3:",7215,0.0376,60)

expArray = [newExpence1,newExpence2,newExpence3]  #adding element to array

print expArray[0].getData()[0] # access array elements with index value.
expArray.remove(newExpence1) # remove array elements with index value.
print expArray[0].getData()[0]
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to use classes, that breaks it down very easy. Thank you!